# Adding click event to all selected elements

Tags: jquery

I want to make it so that when you select (click) on an li element it toggles a class.I've tried:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

but nothing happens when I click the list item.

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<input type = "text" placeholder = "New category" id = "category">
<button type = "button" onclick ="addCategory()">Add</button><br>
<ul id = "list">
<li>School</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Fun</li>
</ul>
```

Rest of JS/jQuery:

```
function addCategory() {
    var category = $("#category").val();
    var list = $("#list");
    var li = $("<li>");
    list.append(li);
    li.append(category);
}
 $("li").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
 });
```

Comment: Probably going to need more context here, as well as a more detailed description than "it doesn't work"

Comment: Can you please provide your html please ? There is no reason that your code shouldn't work in the way you wrote it

Comment: Wild guess: that code snippet resides inside the `<head>` element and outside of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the li element. inside the tags is plain text. Maybe it's because elements can be added via a text input field on the click of a button

Comment: @Žiga, then AKA's answer will probably work, although they don't bother explaining the reason why.

Comment: add a fiddle example so we can see whats going wrong

Comment: Where is html ?

Comment: *" elements can be added via a text input field "* - pretty relevant information that you should have included.  You're adding dynamic elements, so you need to use event delegation. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work
See an example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ank9803/h4JXs/5046/).
Jquery works on elements that are present while the event is registered. So we can trick the situation by registering the event on a element which is always present. So the event is registered properly for any `li` on the `document`.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Don't know what you talking about. See here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ank9803/h4JXs/5046/)

Comment: @AKA Because you don't know the HTML, you cannot say that _this will work_

Comment: @AKA More importantly, you've not explained what you've added/changed to make it work and so why this would work vs the original code.   Essentially this is a code-only answer, which is generally considered not-helpful on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this snippet I wrote for you, the code you paste here works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#result").text($("#list").html());
  
  $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("#result").text($("#list").html());
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Click me 1</li>
  <li>Click me 2</li>
  <li>Click me 3</li>
  <li>Click me 4</li>
  <li>Click me 5</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h3>Html code of the list</h3>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Are you correctly referencing jquery before your li subscribing to the click event ?
Are you adding your `li` item dynamically ?